# The Tab1.java from API Demo has exception

Tags: android

I don't know why.All my Tab programs have exception.Even from API Demo.

### Here is the code:

package com.example.android.apis.view;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class Tab1 extends TabActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
  LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.main,tabHost.getTabContentView(), true);
  tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
    .setIndicator("tab1")
    .setContent(R.id.view1));
  tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
    .setIndicator("tab2")
    .setContent(R.id.view2));
  tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3")
    .setIndicator("tab3")
    .setContent(R.id.view3));
 }
}

### Here is the log:

06-13 17:24:38.336: WARN/jdwp(262): Debugger is telling the VM to exit with code=1
06-13 17:24:38.336: INFO/dalvikvm(262): GC lifetime allocation: 2511 bytes
06-13 17:24:38.416: DEBUG/Zygote(30): Process 262 exited cleanly (1)
06-13 17:24:38.456: INFO/ActivityManager(54): Process com.example.android.apis.view (pid 262) has died.
06-13 17:24:38.696: INFO/UsageStats(54): Unexpected resume of com.android.launcher while already resumed in com.example.android.apis.view
06-13 17:24:38.736: WARN/InputManagerService(54): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44dc4b38
06-13 17:24:48.337: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(269): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
06-13 17:24:48.346: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(269): CheckJNI is ON
06-13 17:24:48.856: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(269): --- registering native functions ---
06-13 17:24:49.596: DEBUG/ddm-heap(269): Got feature list request
06-13 17:24:50.576: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(269): Shutting down VM
06-13 17:24:50.576: DEBUG/dalvikvm(269): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit
06-13 17:24:50.576: DEBUG/dalvikvm(269): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down
06-13 17:24:50.576: DEBUG/dalvikvm(269): HeapWorker thread shutting down
06-13 17:24:50.586: DEBUG/dalvikvm(269): HeapWorker thread has shut down
06-13 17:24:50.586: DEBUG/jdwp(269): JDWP shutting down net...
06-13 17:24:50.586: INFO/dalvikvm(269): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 17:24:50.596: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(269): ERROR: thread attach failed
06-13 17:24:50.606: DEBUG/dalvikvm(269): VM cleaning up
06-13 17:24:50.676: DEBUG/dalvikvm(269): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 628628 of 5242880 (11%)
06-13 17:24:51.476: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(278): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
06-13 17:24:51.486: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(278): CheckJNI is ON
06-13 17:24:51.986: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(278): --- registering native functions ---
06-13 17:24:52.746: DEBUG/ddm-heap(278): Got feature list request
06-13 17:24:53.716: DEBUG/ActivityManager(54): Uninstalling process com.example.android.apis.view
06-13 17:24:53.726: INFO/ActivityManager(54): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.android.apis.view/.Tab1 }
06-13 17:24:53.876: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(278): Shutting down VM
06-13 17:24:53.886: DEBUG/dalvikvm(278): DestroyJavaVM waiting for non-daemon threads to exit
06-13 17:24:53.916: DEBUG/dalvikvm(278): DestroyJavaVM shutting VM down
06-13 17:24:53.926: DEBUG/dalvikvm(278): HeapWorker thread shutting down
06-13 17:24:53.936: DEBUG/dalvikvm(278): HeapWorker thread has shut down
06-13 17:24:53.936: DEBUG/jdwp(278): JDWP shutting down net...
06-13 17:24:53.936: INFO/dalvikvm(278): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
06-13 17:24:53.957: DEBUG/dalvikvm(278): VM cleaning up
06-13 17:24:54.026: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(278): ERROR: thread attach failed
06-13 17:24:54.146: DEBUG/dalvikvm(278): LinearAlloc 0x0 used 638596 of 5242880 (12%)
06-13 17:24:54.286: INFO/ActivityManager(54): Start proc com.example.android.apis.view for activity com.example.android.apis.view/.Tab1: pid=285 uid=10054 gids={1015}
06-13 17:24:54.676: DEBUG/ddm-heap(285): Got feature list request
06-13 17:24:55.006: WARN/ActivityThread(285): Application com.example.android.apis.view is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
06-13 17:24:55.126: INFO/System.out(285): Sending WAIT chunk
06-13 17:24:55.186: INFO/dalvikvm(285): Debugger is active
06-13 17:24:55.378: INFO/System.out(285): Debugger has connected
06-13 17:24:55.386: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:55.586: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:55.796: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:55.996: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:56.196: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:56.406: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:56.606: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:56.806: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:57.016: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:57.216: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:57.416: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:57.626: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:57.836: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:58.039: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:58.246: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:58.451: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:58.656: INFO/System.out(285): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-13 17:24:58.866: INFO/System.out(285): debugger has settled (1367)
06-13 17:24:59.126: ERROR/gralloc(54): [unregister] handle 0x129980 still locked (state=40000001)
06-13 17:25:03.816: WARN/ActivityManager(54): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
06-13 17:25:04.906: WARN/ActivityManager(54): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44d60e10 com.example.android.apis.view/.Tab1}

Comment: NOTE TO POSTER: you need to format your posts so they are readable.... there is no way anyone is going to want to dig through your code/logs when they look like that.

Comment: also, it is not very kosher to just post your code and say "please fix it"

Answer (score 0):

You say you got this code from the API? do you mean from google? Whenever you import code from another source in Android Dev there could be any one of a hundred different problems. Here are some (to name a few):

1. you dont have all of the files (layouts, images, and other resources)
2. the files are in the wrong location
3. BIG ONE: there are errors in your manifest xml. Often times you can forget to add activities to the manifest before running your app.
4. you copy/pasted code off the internet without knowing what it does or how it works (this is also common). make sure that you read all documentation that came with the demo, and make sure you understand what each line of code is doing BEFORE you try to use it.

If i had to guess which one of these is your problem, its most likely the manifest.